# Batch renaming txt files to match folder, all in same directory?

Tags: bash

In ~/Desktop/a/ , I have folders (with names that have spaces) and txt files in the form:

```
100 description of project A
100_notes.txt
200 description of project B
200_notes.txt
```

What I would like:

```
100 description of project A
100 description of project A.txt
200 description of project B
200 description of project B.txt
```

This is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/a/
for i in *; do
  mv "$i/${f%.txt}" "$i.txt";
done
```

I'm trying it with test files, and it renames the folder to have a .txt extension, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong quotes. You appear to have the correct open quote and the wrong close quote (both should be the same).

Comment: What is `100 description, 100_notes.txt,` the name of? It's unclear what things are named here. Is the last comma part of the filename name?

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol That's an immediate problem, but also notice that they are using an unset variable `f` in the `mv` command, and that removing the final `.txt` filename suffix won't remove the `_notes` bit.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I've edited it to clarify. The commas aren't part of the names. 100 description is the folder name, 100_notes is the txt file name.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I thought that "f%" means "file"? Is that not the case?

Comment: No, `${f%.txt}` takes the shell variable `$f` and removes the string `.txt` from the end of its value.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol, thanks. I fixed the quotes and ran it, but now it just renames the folder to have a txt extension.

Comment: What would happen with a file `NNN_notes.txt` if there is no corresponding directory `NNN description`?  I'm asking because you make a point of saying that there are directories with these specific names. You are not just asking about how to change `_notes` into `description` in the filenames.

Comment: @Kusalananda, So I should replace the f% with something else? Or use it, but have it copy the whole string?

If there's no corresponding directory, I thought it would just skip it. I'd like it to know that a folder and txt are paired if they have the same ID number (i.e., 100 or 200), and if so, copy the folder's filename and rename the txt to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

for notes in ./???_notes.txt
do
    if [ ! -f "$notes" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    num=${notes%_notes.txt}

    set -- "$num "*/
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        echo 'More than one directory found:' >&2
        printf '\t%s\n' "$@" >&2
        printf 'Skipping %s...\n' "$notes" >&2
        continue
    elif [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
        printf 'No directory matching "%s" found\n' "$num */" >&2
        printf 'Skipping %s...\n' "$notes" >&2
        continue
    fi

    printf 'Would rename "%s" into "%s"\n' "$notes" "${1%/}.txt"
    # mv -i "$notes" "${1%/}.txt"
done
```

This script would iterate over all the `NNN_notes.txt` files in the current directory.  For each file, the number `NNN` (which may be any three-letter string) is extracted and used to detect any *directory* called `NNN` followed by a space and an arbitrary string.

If a single directory is found, the file is renamed accordingly (the actual renaming is commented out for safety).  If more than one directory or no directory is found, a message pointing this out is displayed.

The parameter substitution `${variable%string}` removes the string `string` from the end of the value of `$variable`.  The `set` command, when used as in this script, sets the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc. to the things matching the given filename globbing pattern (in this script, we want the pattern to match exactly one directory). The value `$#` is the number of such positional parameters.

The way I have written this script, it would be executable by both `bash` and `/bin/sh`.  It does not use any "bashisms".

A `bash`-only version:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for notes in ./???_notes.txt
do
    num=${notes%_notes.txt}

    dirs=( "$num "*/ )
    if [ "${#dirs[@]}" -gt 1 ]; then
        echo 'More than one directory found:' >&2
        printf '\t%s\n' "${dirs[@]}" >&2
        printf 'Skipping %s...\n' "$notes" >&2
        continue
    elif [ "${#dirs[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
        printf 'No directory matching "%s" found\n' "$num */" >&2
        printf 'Skipping %s...\n' "$notes" >&2
        continue
    fi

    printf 'Would rename "%s" into "%s"\n' "$notes" "${dirs[0]%/}.txt"
    # mv -i "$notes" "${dirs[0]%/}.txt"
done
```

The biggest difference here is that we use a named array `dirs` to hold the possible expansions of the pattern `"$num "*/` and that we use the `nullglob` shell option to make non-matching filename patterns expand to nothing.